# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () In React App

Tags: json, reactjs, npm

I am not able to load a JSON file in the browser.
I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load /resumeData.json?_=1533629733770:1 resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Any help would be appreciated.

I am attaching the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: I think your request was not understood by your server. Could you please provide some code where you submit your request to your server.

Comment: Where does `/resumeData.json` reside?

Comment: /resumeData.json file is in public folder and components are in src folder @SungKim